# Locked doors in Vizima outskirts

Tags: the-witcher

There are a lot of locked doors in Vizima Outskirts, and I can't find a way to open them. Is there some kind of kley that I should find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no key for those doors, and no way to open them. Apparently, a lot of people have spent a lot of time on this issue.